# Erro de Masterpage não localizada

Tags: asp.net

Meu site que esta dando erro de "MasterPage não localizada", e todos os arquivos foram publicados:

[image: Print de Erro.]

Comment: Sua MasterPage está no root da aplicação, conforme indica o path? Tente remover o `~/` para ver se muda algo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

o "~" é mapeado para a url raiz do site, no seu caso "/". No entanto, ao que parece, sua masterpage está dentro de novosite. Logo, considerando sua situação atual, vc precisaria ou mudar o path da masterpage para "~/novosite/SKTI.Master" ou adicionar uma pasta "MasterPages", por exemplo, ao seu projeto no mesmo nível que a pasta novosite.
Uma outra opção é vc publicar direto no diretório raiz da página(na mesma página em que novosite está contida).

Comment: Obrigado a todos.
Funcionou.
Estranho que o arquivo de origem está normal e isso só acontece no arquivo que foi publicado, como se o vs2010 tivesse alterado.

Comment: O que acontece é que vc está publicando em uma pasta dentro do diretório virtual configurado, porém ele busca a masterpage a a partir da raiz(/SKTI.Master) quando, na verdade, a masterpage está dentro de novosite(/novosite/SKTI.Master).